# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.framework.op_def_registry' has no attribute 'get_registered_ops'

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-hub

I am trying to retrain the inception v3 model.

However, I got stuck by an error

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.framework.op_def_registry' has no attribute 'get_registered_ops'

in the tensorflow_hub native_module.py file.

Why do I get this error?

```
missing_ops = graph_ops - set(op_def_registry.get_registered_ops().keys())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`get_registered_ops()` has been removed in recent versions of. Be sure to use tensorflow-hub>=0.7.0 to pick up on the black magic at https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/blob/v0.7.0/tensorflow_hub/native_module.py#L50

Comment: I am using tensorflow-hub 0.10.0 and still getting this error. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did anyone manage to solve this? I suddenly started having this problem, I tried re-installing the Object Detection API, but had no success

Answer (score 1):

1. Use Tensorflow 1.11 or greater. However, don't go on to use Tensorflow 2.*.
2. Also, for the current latest version of tensorflow-hub 0.10.0, you need tf >= 1.15.0.
   Thus, best to use 1.15.0 <= tf < 2.* along with tf-hub latest(0.10.0).